# Two 'If Statements' is my syntax correct (functions.php) and what is 'false'

Tags: functions

The following code works great.

I would just like to know if it is correct to have two 'If' Statements like I have done?

(The purpose of this snippet is to replace the generic "Category, Tag" and replace with custom text).

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'my_theme_archive_title' );
/**
 * Remove archive labels.
 * 
 * @param  string $title Current archive title to be displayed.
 * @return string        Modified archive title to be displayed.
 */
function my_theme_archive_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_tax('us_state') ) {
        $title = single_term_title( 'Conferences In&nbsp;', false );
    }
    if ( is_tax('country') ) {
        $title = single_term_title( 'CConferences In&nbsp;', false );
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Also - what is the **false** statement at the end for? Is it stating whether JQuery needs to be loaded?

Thanks for all feedback - I just want to make sure I am doing it correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use elseif for the second if statement:

```
$title1 = single_term_title( 'Conferences In&nbsp;', false );
$title2 = single_term_title( 'CConferences In&nbsp;', false );

add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'my_theme_archive_title' );
function my_theme_archive_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_tax('us_state') ) {
        $title1;
    }
    elseif ( is_tax('country') ) {
        $title2;
    }
    else {
return $title;
}
}
```

You can read here about true/false https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_term_title/

Comment: thank you veryvmuch for your help

Comment: This code won't work. If the first two conditions are true then the title won't appear at all, because it's not being returned.

Comment: I edited the code by excluding the variables and should work now, haven't tested it though